# Bash script to open up a terminal and cd into a directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script, which when run from the command line, will `cd` into a default directory and then open up the folder in the file-browser:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  # unless $1 is specified, cd into main proj
  cd code/ruby/my-main-proj
else
  # cd into project specified by $1
  cd code/ruby/$1
fi

# open folder in file manager    
pcmanfm .
```

This is great, it gives me two things:

1. a command-prompt whose working directory is set to the project I want
2. a file-browser for the same project

The trouble is that I would like to run my bash script by *clicking* on a **desktop icon** but in it's current form, the terminal does not open up, just the file browser..

So I've made a modification to try and get the terminal to open too:

```
then
  # unless $1 is specified, cd into main proj
  x-terminal-emulator -e "cd code/ruby/my-main-proj"
else
  # code same as before
```

But while the terminal does open, it just displays a blank screen, with no prompt or PWD.
How can I get a terminal to open up, and have it's working directory change to the one I'm trying to specify in my bash script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't get it to work with x-terminal-emulator, but with the standard
gnome terminal.

```
user@MacBookPro:~$ gnome-terminal --working-directory=~/code/ruby/my-main-proj
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahh, thanks, the --working-directory flag seems to fix this

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you're not executing a shell in your temrinal emulator, you're trying to execute `cd`, which is a shell command, not an actual shell (not even an actual executable for that matter).

You could make a desktop entry file that starts a shell in a custom working directory, like this:

**MyProject.desktop**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=x-terminal-emulator
Path=/path/to/code/ruby/my-main-proj
Name=My Project
```

Note the **Path=…** above.